# Hide the soft keyboard on blur, in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, hide, android-softkeyboard

I have an PhoneGap application, it's working properly. The only thing bugging me is the way PhoneGap handles the soft keyboard; it doesn't hide when an input is blur'ed. It does do this in iOS, but it even stays when loading a new page in Android.

I had a look at this:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/27915465/How%20to%20show%20and%20hide%20soft%20keyboard%20in%20Android

and this:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard

but they both did not work for me, any ideas?

Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin you linked to worked for me (had exactly the same issue):

```
$("#eingabe").blur(); //for ios
var softkeyboard = window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard;
softkeyboard.hide();
```

You probably used Cordova 2.0.0 (or greater) and didn't modify the plugin files (which are written for Phonegap < 2.0).

Here are the updated files (the ones I use):

### softkeyboard.js

```
cordova.plugins = cordova.plugins || {};

cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard = {
show: function (win, fail) {
    return cordova.exec(
        function (args) { if (win !== undefined) { win(args); } },
        function (args) { if (fail !== undefined) { fail(args); } },
        'SoftKeyBoard', 'show', []
    );
},

hide: function (win, fail) {
    return cordova.exec(
        function (args) { if (win !== undefined) { win(args); } },
        function (args) { if (fail !== undefined) { fail(args); } },
        'SoftKeyBoard', 'hide', []
    );
},

isShowing: function (win, fail) {
    return cordova.exec(
        function (args) { if (win !== undefined) { win(args); } },
        function (args) { if (fail !== undefined) { fail(args); } },
        'SoftKeyBoard', 'isShowing', []
    );
}
};
```

### SoftKeyBoard.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugins;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class SoftKeyBoard extends Plugin {
public SoftKeyBoard () { }

public void showKeyBoard () {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(webView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    ((InputMethodManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(webView, 0);
}

public void hideKeyBoard() {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webView.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public boolean isKeyBoardShowing() {
    // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
    int heightDiff = webView.getRootView().getHeight() - webView.getHeight();
    return (100 < heightDiff);
}

public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
    if (action.equals("show")) {
        this.showKeyBoard();
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "done");
    } else if (action.equals("hide")) {
        this.hideKeyBoard();
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
    } else if (action.equals("isShowing")) {
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, this.isKeyBoardShowing());
    } else {
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
    }
}
}
```

### Modify config.xml

Also make sure that you add the following line in "**res/xml/config.xml**":

```
<plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard" />
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct, i haven't tested it, but by the looks of it, its going to work. I was using a much lower version of PhoneGap at the time. I think they fixed all the keyboard problems in Cordova 2.0.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with Cordova 3.0? The plugin hasn't been updated to 3.0, and cordova no longer has cordova.api.plugin as a method of making plugins work.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and saved my head from excessive scratching! (also does not need a plugin)

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};
```

The solution was found [here](http://uihacker.blogspot.cz/2011/10/javascript-hide-ios-soft-keyboard.html), where you can find a non `jQuery` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that independent of the state of the keyboard, the Java will call:

```
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, this.isKeyBoardShowing());
```

The 2nd parameter here contains either true or false.  So your javascript callback should be:

```
cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard.isShowing(function (showing) {
    if (showing) {
        console.error("############ keyboard is open");
    } else {
        console.error("############ keyboard is closed");
    }
}
,function () {
    // never called
    console.error("############ never called!");
});
```

It seems that Cordova expects both the success and failure javascript callbacks even though in this case only the success callback is called in both possible outcomes.